# using javax.tools.JavaCompiler etc

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, java-compiler-api

I am looking for working examples of [Oracle's Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) usage. I want to build something close to `javac` to customize/extend errors logging capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/) (the SSCCE Text Based Compiler).  The source is available in [`stbc.zip`](http://pscode.org/stbc/stbc.zip).

[image: Compilation failed] [image: Compiled OK]